# How to take arbitrary number of parentheses from user for add function

Tags: python

```
add(5)(10)(20)
```

How can I to supply an arbitrary number of parentheses to add numbers?

Comment: Why not `sum([5, 10, 20])`?

Comment: Why not `add(5, 10, 20)`? (although I prefer the @FullName `sum` option)

Comment: also, I suspect that this question is related to an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 3):

You could create a class like so:

```
class add(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value= value

    def __call__(self, value):
        self.value+= value
        return self

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)


print add(5)(10)(20)
# output: 35
```

Comment: I guess I'm not totally surprised this is possible with python. It's heartbreaking to think someone would rely upon it tho.

Comment: this is using a bazooka for a fly :D but why not ? (Fulln name comment is the easiest I think)

Comment: Clever code rears its head immediately. `print add(5)(10)(20) + add(5)(10)(20)` `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'add' and 'add'`

Comment: @naomik That functionality can be [add](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__)ed if necessary. OP didn't mention anything like that, so I kept the code to the minimum.

Comment: You're right, if the OP doesn't mention, we should assume that all computed values are just going to be used with `print`. Forget that numbers can do all sorts of other things.

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible, or at least it *should* be if the language you're using is worth anything. You're asking for a function to return two different types, which is inviting a a disaster.

1. sometimes it should return a function that takes the next number to add
2. other times it should return the sum of the previous inputs.

What? Take a step back and ask yourself what kind of design that is. You would need need some way to notify the function that you're done giving inputs and now you want the computed value.

Think about it, the function might look like this

```
def add (sum):
  print(sum)
  return lambda x: add(sum + x)

add(1)(3)(4)(5)(10)(20)

# 1
# 4
# 8
# 13
# 23
# 43
# => None
```

But there's no way to let the function know to return a final value unless you change the api somehow.

---

You could change the api to return the computed value when the users enters a `0` or something. Great idea right? Very clever.

```
def add (x):
  def loop(sum, x):
    if x == 0:
      return sum
    else:
      return lambda x: loop(sum + x, x)
  return loop(0, x)

print(add(1)(3)(4)(5)(10)(20)(0))
# 42
```

Hey look, it works where @Rawling's clever code fails. All without adding a bunch of tricks to a class

```
print(add(5)(10)(20)(0) + add(5)(10)(20)(0)) 
# 70
```

---

But still, this is garbage code. No well-designed function should ever behave like this.

Or if your content with being insane, create a class like @Rawing's answer suggests.

Answer (score -1):

What you could do is this:

```
class add(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val= val

    def __call__(self, val=None):
        if not val:
            return self.val
        self.val += val
        return self

add(5)(10)()
>>> 15
```